# Have to define public variables before __construct() in PHP class?

Tags: php, class, oop

To define properties in the class, I see two ways:

## 1

create public variables first, and refer to them inside the __construct() function:

```
<?php
        class User {
        public $name;
        public $email;
    
       public function __construct($name, $email) {
           $this->name = $name;
           $this->email = $email;
       }
    
       public function getType() {
           return $this->type;
       }
    
    } ?>
```

And simply define the properties without defining the public variables:

## 2

```
<?php
   class Cars{
        function __construct($parameter1, $parameter2) {
        $this->model= $parameter1;
        $this->price = $parameter2;
        }
        
        function getPrice(){
        echo $this->price ."<br/>";
        }
       
        function getModel(){
        echo $this->model ." <br/>";
        }
} ?>
```

I'm wondering what is the different usages of these two approaches to define the properties for class in PHP? What's point of using the first option when second option is working the same?

Comment: number 2 is just a bad style

Comment: number 2 also doesn't work for private/protected properties, which is what you normally use in classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, solution 1 and 2 works but the solution 2 is just a bad way to declare class variables.

By strict convention, **always declare your class variables**:

- You can see the variables of your class in one look. And think about others developers which look after you, it's important to know which variables we can find in this class.
- You can define visibility of variables (public, protected, private).